# Main function already defined in visual studio project

Tags: c, visual-studio, program-entry-point

I created windows console program project in visual studio, and made two c language files. Both has same source:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello");
}
```

When I try to compile, compiler screams about having two `main()`s. See below:

[image]

I can't understand. I thought two files in one project works separately. Am I wrong?

Comment: Two files with _exactly_ same source....what you're upto?

Comment: Don't post images. And think about why it is called "**one** project"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are wrong. IIRC, the whole *project* is compiled and then linked to form a single executable.

In a single executable, there can be only one `main()` function.

Answer (score 1):

These two `main` functions are within the same Project. You should have only one `main` function in your program.

Try to implement a `new project`, and then add the `main` function in there.